# Why is that In Android layout - Relative layout some elements are not showing?

Tags: android, xml, layout

Bit new to horizontal and vertical layouts.
When using my relative layout that contains a progress bar, two text views and a footer xml only the header and progress bar are being displayed (in landscape only).

Here is my XML Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/border_rounded">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/layHead"
        layout="@layout/infoheader"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="180dip">
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pbConnect"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:progress="50"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3.0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3.0dp" />
        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tvInfo"
            android:gravity="center" />
        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tvSubInfo"
            android:gravity="center" />
        <include
            android:id="@+id/layFoot"
            layout="@layout/infofooter"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I fix this? Are relative layouts good to use in landscape activities?

Comment: My guess is the TextViews are getting hidden - try using the magic of the `RelativeLayout`: the `android:layout_toRightOf` `android:layout_toLeftOf` `android:layout_above` and `android:layout_below` attributes. Try putting `android:layout_below="@id/pbConnect"` in one of your TextViews

Answer (score 0):

only progress bar is being displayed because in progress bar you are using `fill_parent` for layout width that's why it's taking whole parent width. Either use `weigthSum` in linear layout or use `Relative Layout`

Comment: Only for the width, the height shouldn't block out the TextViews as well?\

Comment: height will block when you will be using layout_height=match_parent and running the app in portrait mode

Comment: The progress bar height is set to 55dp - That shouldn't take the whole screen? The linearlayout is taking the whole screen though and that could explain the footer being gone?